# shiny app data subsetting not working

Tags: r, shiny

Im building a shiny app. The ui should react everytime the person modify the "Partido" and the "Estado" questions, but its not happennig. Here's the server and the ui:

here's the part of the server that should react:

```
*shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  reactivePoll({
if(input$partido == "DEM"){
  deputado <- subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM")
  if(input$estado == "AC"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado, votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "AC")}
  else if(input$estado == "AM"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "AM")}
  else if(input$estado == "AP"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "AP")}
  else if(input$estado == "CE"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "CE")}
  else if(input$estado == "DF"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "DF")}
  else if(input$estado == "GO"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "GO")}
  else if(input$estado == "MA"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "MA")}
  else if(input$estado == "MS"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "MS")}
  else if(input$estado == "MT"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "MT")}
  else if(input$estado == "PA"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "PA")}
  else if(input$estado == "PR"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "PR")}
  else if(input$estado == "RJ"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "RJ")}
  else if(input$estado == "RO"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "RO")}
  else if(input$estado == "RR"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "RR")}
  else if(input$estado == "RS"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "RS")}
  else if(input$estado == "SC"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "SC")}
  else if(input$estado == "SP"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "SP")}
  else if(input$estado == "TO"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "TO")}
  else if(input$estado == "AL"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "AL")}
  else if(input$estado == "BA"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "BA")}
  else if(input$estado == "ES"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "ES")}
  else if(input$estado == "MG"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "MG")}
  else if(input$estado == "PB"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "PB")}
  else if(input$estado == "PE"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "PE")}
  else if(input$estado == "PI"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "PI")}
  if(input$estado == "RN"){
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "RN")}
  else{
    deputado <- subset(subset(votos$Deputado,  votos$Partido == "DEM"), 
                       votos$Estado == "SE")}
}
})*
```

#

and the ui:

```
*library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
votos <- read.csv("votos1.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, na.strings="NA",
                  encoding = "UTF-8")
part <- levels(votos$Partido)
lev <- levels(votos$Estado)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Votação do Impeachment - 2016"),
  p("Autora: Bruna Wundervald"),
  hr(),sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId="partido",
                  label="Escolha o partido do Deputado",
                  choices=part,
                 selected=""),
      selectInput(inputId="estado",
                  label="Escolha o estado do Deputado",
                  choices=lev,
      selected=""),
      conditionalPanel("input.partido",
                       selectInput(inputId="deputado",
                  label="Escolha o Deputado",
                  choices=deputado,
                  selected=""))
  ),

  mainPanel(
   tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
               # tabPanel(title="Introdução",
                #         verbatimTextOutput("intro")),
                tabPanel(title="Fala",
                         verbatimTextOutput("fala"))
    )))))*
```

it simply doesnt work :(

(the server part its repeated for another options of "Partidos")

Comment: what do you mean by "not work"? what is the error?

Comment: what do you mean by "not work"? what is the error? can i have a dummy votos1.csv file?

Comment: hi there. when I change the input (the "estado" or the "partido" input), nothing changes in the ui (and that was the idea). its no dummy file. tks for answering :)

Comment: Hi @BrunaWundervald, welcome to SO :) I think you misunderstood AHC. He was probably asking if you could provide a possible example of your data so he could reproduce your code (in case your data was confidential).

Comment: please use `switch` instead of `if else` its much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**
I am not sure what you exactly want to do I prepared something by my own for you :)

server.ui

```
votos <- read.csv("~/Downloads/appp/votos1.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, na.strings="NA",
                  encoding = "UTF-8")
part <- levels(votos$Partido)
lev <- levels(votos$Estado)
deputado <- levels(votos$Deputado)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { # added session

    data1 <- reactive({

      retval <- votos # show the whole dataset

      # show rows only with members of partido
      if (input$partido != "nadie") { 
        retval <- retval[retval$Partido == input$partido, ]
      }

      # show only rows with a particular estado or
      # only with partido and estado
      if (input$estado != "nadie") { 
        retval <- retval[retval$Estado == input$estado, ]
      }

      # show a particular deputado
      if (input$deputado != "nadie") {
        retval <- retval[retval$Deputado == input$deputado, ]
      }

      retval <- retval[ ,c("Deputado", "Fala")]
      retval
    })

  observe({
    # if you select a particular partido then you will be able to choose one
    # particular deputado of partido
    if (input$partido != "nadie") { 
      new_choices <- as.character(votos[votos$Partido == input$partido, "Deputado"])

      updateSelectInput(session, "deputado", 
                        choices = c("nadie", new_choices),
                        selected = "nadies")
    }
    if (input$partido == "nadie") {
      updateSelectInput(session, "deputado", 
                        choices = c("nadie", deputado),
                        selected = "nadie")

    }
  })

  output$fala <- renderTable({ data1() })

  })
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(


  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Votação do Impeachment - 2016"),
    p("Autora: Bruna Wundervald"),
    hr(),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = "partido", 
                    label = "Escolha o partido do Deputado", 
                    choices = c("nadie", part), 
                    selected = "nadie"), 

        selectInput(inputId="estado",
                    label = "Escolha o estado do Deputado", 
                    choices = c("nadie", lev), 
                    selected = "nadie"), 

        conditionalPanel("input.partido",
                         selectInput(inputId = "deputado", 
                                     label = "Escolha o Deputado", 
                                     choices = c("nadie", deputado), # changed
                                     selected = "nadie"))
      ),

      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
                    # tabPanel(title="Introdução",
                    #         verbatimTextOutput("intro")),
                    tabPanel(title="Fala",
                             tableOutput("fala"))
                             # verbatimTextOutput("fala"))
        )))))

))
```

Comment: hi. thank you very much! unfortunately i'll have access to the files again only tomorrow (its not in any git repository yet), so i'll have to try this later. but its probably going to work. thank you for your attention!

Comment: data1 <- reactive({ 
    if (input$partido == "DEM") {
      deputado <- subset(votos$Deputado, 
                         subset = votos$Partido == "DEM",
                         filter == input$estado)}

Comment: else if (input$partido == "PV") {
        deputado <- subset(votos$Deputado, 
                           subset = votos$Partido == "PV",
                           filter == input$estado)}
      else if (input$partido == "Rede") {
        deputado <- subset(votos$Deputado, 
                           subset = votos$Partido == "Rede",
                           filter == input$estado)}

Comment: else{
        deputado <- subset(votos$Deputado, 
                           subset = votos$Partido == "SD",
                           filter == input$estado)}
    
    return(as.data.frame(deputado))
  })
  
  
  output$table <- renderTable({ data1() })
  
  fala <- reactive(
    subset(votos$Fala, votos$Deputado == input$deputado)
  )
  
  output$faladep <- renderPrint(
    cat("-----", "fala", sep="\n")
  )

  
})

Comment: with renderPrint it kind works. but its not filtering by state ("estado")

Comment: Is `votos` a list in which you have a dataframe `Deputado`?

Comment: votos is a data frame and Deputado is character [its a variable of the dataframe votos]

Comment: Did you try to use instead `subset` function `[` operator? 
Do you get any error? (I guess you get an error from `subset` function,  because I wrote by mistake `filter == input$estado` instead of `filter = input$estado`). If you will do the subsetting properly it should work :). By the way - the parameter `filter` in `subset` selects a column(s) in a dataframe but you try to subset a character vector. (In my above answer I was assuming that you have a list in which you have a dataframe Deputado). Without small example (fake) dataset it is very difficult to help :)

Comment: Sorry for my mistake with `filter`.

Comment: hey there. tks for answering again :) here's the dataset im using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-TOuY2yPDa-eWZuX01QeDBBMkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry for taking so long to show you the dataset, its not even confidential or anything

Comment: It is no problem.  I will try tomorrow

Comment: I updated the answer...hopefully it is more or less what you were planning to do :)